# JavaScript SwapImage with multiple images and getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover, getelementbyid

I wanted to implement a `swapImage` on my site that would swap one image on `mouseover`, and another image on `mouseout`. Essentially, with the solution I found I could also probably swap different images for `mousedown` and `mouseup` even.

I have this happening in 8 different nested tabs, all of which are on the same page.

The javascript looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function swapImageFiat(imgID, imgSrc) {
        var theImage = document.getElementById(imgID)
        theImage.src = imgSrc;
    }

    function swapImageHarley(imgID, imgSrc) {
        var theImage = document.getElementById(imgID)
        theImage.src = imgSrc;
    }

    function swapImageHotWheels(imgID, imgSrc) {
        var theImage = document.getElementById(imgID)
        theImage.src = imgSrc;
    }

    function swapImageVoltron(imgID, imgSrc) {
        var theImage = document.getElementById(imgID)
        theImage.src = imgSrc;
    }

    function swapImageBenchmade(imgID, imgSrc) {
        var theImage = document.getElementById(imgID)
        theImage.src = imgSrc;
    }

    function swapImageCrew(imgID, imgSrc) {
        var theImage = document.getElementById(imgID)
        theImage.src = imgSrc;
    }

    function swapImageReuters(imgID, imgSrc) {
        var theImage = document.getElementById(imgID)
        theImage.src = imgSrc;
    }

    function swapImageMarsVolta(imgID, imgSrc) {
        var theImage = document.getElementById(imgID)
        theImage.src = imgSrc;
    }

    function preLoadImages() {
        for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var theImage = new Image();
            theImage.src = arguments[i];
        }
    }
</script>
```

And the inline code for **each** image would be essentially this:

```
<img class="diagram" src="img/fiat.gif" id="imgToSwapFiat" alt="Diagram" data-title="Fiat Diagram" onClick="swapImageFiat('imgToSwapFiat', 'img/fiat-animated.gif')" onmouseout="swapImageFiat('imgToSwapFiat', 'fiat.gif')" height="189" width="358" />
```

I would like to be able to use **less IDs**, less of the same repetitive script, and shorter inline code.
But I also want the flexibility of being able to *just* change the images and their IDs, rather than fussing with JQuery or other script. This is why I'm using `getElementById`.

> Is there a more ***efficient*** way for me to write that JavaScript, and/or Inline code?

Also

> Is there a way for the image to **swap back to the original** after the animation **stops playing**, rather than on mouse-out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, sure there is. As Jan mentions - all of your functions are identical. There's no need to duplicate them all. Also, you can remove the inline event-handler code from your html, simply attaching the mouseover/mouseout or mousedown/mouseup.

Simply add a new attribute to each image that you wish to have the effect for, then runs some js on page-load to attach the handler.

Here, I've just used (and checked for the existance of) custom attributes. If the image has them, I attach handlers. If not, it's no different to any other normal image. This should be nice an re-usable and little effort to use.

As for resetting the image once the animated gif has played, I'd probably look at Jan's first suggestion. A slight modification on the idea would be to make the last frame transparent, then simply position the animated image over (z-index higher) the static one.
When it's done, you'll see the original image again. You'll have to decide on a system for refreshing these images, should they need to be re-played. I'm not sure, perhaps setting their src to '', before setting it back to the animated.gif would cause the animation to play from the start again - you'd have to check if to decided to attempt such an approach.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

function mInit()
{
    var imgList = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var i, n = imgList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (imgList[i].hasAttribute('img2'))
            imgList[i].addEventListener('click', imgClick, false);
        if (imgList[i].hasAttribute('img3'))
            imgList[i].addEventListener('mouseover', imgHover, false);
        if (imgList[i].hasAttribute('img4'))
            imgList[i].addEventListener('mouseout', imgOut, false);
    }
}

// because these function are attached with addEventListener, the 'this'
// keyword refers to the image element itself. No need for IDs..
function imgClick()
{
    this.src = this.getAttribute('img2');
}
function imgHover()
{
    this.src = this.getAttribute('img3');
}
function imgOut()
{
    this.src = this.getAttribute('img4');
}


window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src='img/gladiators.png'>  <!-- this image won't be touched, as it doesn't have img1, img2 or img3 attributes -->
    <img src='img/opera.svg' img2='img/chromeEyes.svg' img3='img/rss16.png' img4='img/girl2.png'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works like a dream. I wanted to ask a follow up question. In the event that you want to return to the original on mouse-out. Is there a way for `imgOut` to return you to the URL inside `src=""` rather than specifying the same URL again.

Comment: Great. I suppose you could just add another attribute to the images, 'orig' perhaps. If you really wanted to keep your html to a minimum, you could omit the src attribute for these multi-soured images. Then in the init javasript, you could set the img src to the appropriate attribute - most likely 'orig'

Comment: What if I replace **img4** in `function imgOut(){this.src = this.getAttribute('img4');}` with **src** - so, `function imgOut(){this.src = this.getAttribute('src');}` - and then just have the HTML look something like this `<img class="diagram" src="diagram.gif" img2="diagram-animated.gif" img4 height="200" width="359" />` - I tested it in chrome, everything seems to be working. But, **is it valid?**

Comment: @vitaly87 - Good question! Not quite sure where you'd go to check that. In chrome at least, the canvas doesn't work like that for it's width/height.-If you set them in the html then override them in the css, you get the same value if you ask for .width and getAttibute('width') (you have to use offsetWidth or clientWidth to get the actual value) I suppose if the attrib didn't stick over several browsers, you could always _create_ an attrib called orig during init and copy the src to it to, I guess. :shrug:

Comment: I think you misunderstood. In the html what would normally look like `img4="URL"` or `img4=""`, is simply `img4`. This has nothing to do with height and width. I did this because JavaScript is looking for attribute `img4` in order to know that it should perform `imgOut` but I don't want to specify a URL for `img4` because it's redundant. So, since I changed `this.src = src` on `imgOut` in the JavaScript, I figured I don't **have to** specify any value for the `img4` attribute. So I didn't, and it worked, but I wonder if this is semantically wrong, and may cause issues on some browsers, etc?

Comment: No, I've understood what you've said this time to be fundamentally the same as what you said earlier. The point Re: width is, that an element has an attribute. This may be set via the html or setAttribute. In the case of the example I mentioned, setting one in code alters the other.

Answer (score 2):

Use `this` instead of the element ID since your function eventually need the actual element object.

The script example:

```
function swapImageFiat(imgEle, imgSrc) {
    imgEle.src = imgSrc;
}
```

The image HTML example:

```
<img src="initial.jpg" onclick="swapImageFiat(this, 'clicked.jpg')" onmouseover="swapImageFiat(this, 'hovered.jpg')" onmouseout="swapImageFiat(this, 'left.jpg')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Jay has a good suggestion for your functions, which all do the same thing. If you remove the names from your functions you'll see they are otherwise identical. And the function name makes no difference at all, in this case it's just the arguments you pass to the function that matters.

> Is there a way for the image to swap back to the original after the
>   animation stops playing, rather than on mouse-out?

You could make the gifs non-looping and make the last frame of the animation the same as the original image. AFAIK there's no way to detect which frame an animated gif is on through Javascript.

If you really want it to return to the original image, you could animate the image completely through Javascript: Write a function that preloads all the images (or a spritemap) and then load them frame by frame.